# Drawing a function in R

Tags: r, function, plot, ggplot2

I just started using R in class and I'm trying to draw this function:

[image: function]

First of all, here is my attemp at defining it.

```
> f<-function(x)
+ if(x<0) {
+ sin(x)
+ } else if (x>=2) {
+ 4*exp(x-2)
+ } else {
+ x^2 }
```

I think it's correct given the results I get:

```
> f(1)
[1] 1
> f(0)
[1] 0
> f(-1)
[1] -0.841471
> f(2)
[1] 4
> f(3)
[1] 10.87313
```

So now I want to draw it but I'm not sure which command does it correctly. I've tried *plot(f,x,y)* being x & y any values such as (-4,4) or (-2,3) but R gives me a warning message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Try `curve` and be sure to vectorize it first:

```
fv <- Vectorize(f)
curve(fv, -4, 4)
```

giving (continued after screenshot):

[image: screenshot]

**2)** Alternately define `f` in a vectorized way right from the start:

```
g <- function(x) ifelse(x < 0, sin(x), ifelse(x >= 2, 4 * exp(x-2), x^2))
curve(g, -4, 4)
```

**3)** This would also work using `fv` or `g`:

```
x <- seq(-4, 4, .1)
plot(x, fv(x), type = "l")
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `ggplot` and [**the example at this blog**](http://t-redactyl.io/blog/2016/03/creating-plots-in-r-using-ggplot2-part-9-function-plots.html)

```
library(ggplot2)

f <- function(x)
{
    return(ifelse(x <= 0, sin(x), ifelse(x >= 2, 4 * exp(x-2), x^2)))
}

ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-4, 4)), aes(x = x)) +
               stat_function(fun = f)
```

[**Live Example**](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=YYR6Ifs1)
[image: screenshot]

Comment: doesn't work, you should vectorise the function with ifelse